# Can MYSQLI prepare statements independently of execution?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a site that makes heavy use of a search function. I am exploring ways to speed up and smooth the search.

My question is, can I declare a *Mysqli Query* and establish the *Connection/Prepare* independently of actually executing the query and binding the results and parameters?

This way I can declare a query and connection only once, assumably saving some processing time. Then mess with the parameters and results of the query independently.

The below code select *x & y* from a table. These two variable will always be the ones being selected, and the connection will always be the same. The only changing element of the below code is the parameter binded onto *?*.

```
$query = "SELECT x, y
          FROM z
          WHERE x = ? ";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
```

Loop through an array and run query for each element.

```
foreach($array as $key) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$key);
    $stmt->execute();       
    $stmt->bind_result($x, $y);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        //LALALALALAL
    }
    $stmt->free_result();
}
```

Are there any inherent issues with this method?
Is it worth the trouble to even do it this way? Is it beneficial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure you can, that's one of the big benefits of prepared statements... a single prepare, and the db server will cache the prepared query so it only needs to execute it each time with the new bind values

Comment: Like Mark said, of course you can. The only problem is that your search won't get any significant speed-ups. When databases search, they are I/O bound. What your optimization does is saving CPU time. However, CPU is rarely an issue with searches - hard disk is the one causing problems. Basically, the optimization you are thinking about (prepare upfront) is good. It's just questionable to what point it will optimize the actual searches.